# bytearray.fromhex doesn't convert when no letters in number

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex, arrays

I am trying to convert a number (of arbitrary size, possibly very long) to its corresponding string of bytes. For example, inputting the number 1094795585 (base 10), which is 0x41414141 (base 16), should return "\x41\x41\x41\x41".

Currently I have:

```
def number_to_bytes(number):
    hex_string = hex(number).rstrip("L").lstrip("0x")
    return bytearray.fromhex(hex_string.decode("hex"))
```

When I input the number 1094795585 (0x41414141), I get the error "odd-length string".

When I input the number 1094795584 (0x41414140), I get the error "non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 2".

This makes me think that Python is adding some sort of invisible character in the `hex_string`. Is this the case?

How can I achieve the correct conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** decode the string from hex; drop the `.decode('hex')` call. You need to pass in actual hex *digits*, not a bytestring with codepoints based on those digits.

Compare the difference:

```
>>> hex(1094795584)[2:]
'41414140'
>>> hex(1094795584)[2:].decode('hex')
'AAA@'
```

By decoding you are already producing the very bytes you wanted `bytesarray.fromhex()` to produce; you could just use `bytesarray(hex_string.decode('hex'))` in that case.

You can use `format()` to produce a hex format for your number that doesn't include the `0x` prefix, nor a `L` postfix for long integers:

```
import math

def number_to_bytes(number):
    byte_count = int(math.log(number, 256)) + 1
    hex_string = '{:0{}x}'.format(number, byte_count * 2)
    return bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import math
>>> def number_to_bytes(number):
...     nibble_count = int(math.log(number, 256)) + 1
...     hex_string = '{:0{}x}'.format(number, nibble_count * 2)
...     return bytearray.fromhex(hex_string)
...
>>> number_to_bytes(1094795585)
bytearray(b'AAAA')
>>> number_to_bytes(1094795584)
bytearray(b'AAA@')
```

Comment: it won't work if you need zero padding the at position 0 for the hex. e.g. number_to_bytes(5)

Comment: @Amir: ah, yes, indeed. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
import math    
def number_to_bytes(num):
    hex_str = format(num, 'x')
    hex_len = (int(math.log2(num)/8)+1)*2
    return bytearray.fromhex(hex_str.zfill(hex_len))
```